# Facebook Page Tab Application - User Denies Access on OAuth Dialog - How Do I Capture the Error?

Tags: dialog, facebook-oauth, access-denied

Scenario: 
I built a Facebook tab application that requires authorization.
The application is installed on a Facebook page.
When an unauthorized user accesses the application I redirect to the OAuth dialog:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/pages/page name/pageid?sk=app_appid&scope=user_birthday,user_location&display=page

Note the "redirect_uri" is the Application on the installed Facebook page.
So, if the user allows we redirect to the tab application - This works fine!

But, if the user denies access (clicks Cancel button - using new OAuth dialog).
The user is again redirected to the tab application and again redirected to the OAuth dialog.

I have noted from the documentation that when the user denies access the browser will redirect to the "redirect_uri" with the following parameters: error=access_denied&
  error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

But if Facebook is using an additional redirect to my application from the "redirectt_uri": http://www.facebook.com/pages/page name/pageid?sk=app_appid

...the error response seems to be lost.
Note: I can successfully capture the error parameters when setting the "redirect_uri" to the canvas url, but I need to have the redirect_uri formatted to open the application in the context of the installed Page if the user allows access.

How would I capture the error parameters in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a flag to the app_data parameter for the redirect_uri. When the user accesses the application initially, this flag is set. I check for OAuth token, if one does not exist I redirect to the OAuth dialog with a redirect_uri to the application installed on the Fan Page. The redirect_uri now includes the flag in the app_data parameter. So, after "Canceling" the application, Facebook redirects to the installed application on the Fan Page - I then check for the flag and redirect to an error page.